# Spring boot: circular reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

**Hi there**
I am working on scheduling project and facing some issues.
The problem is Application says there is a circular reference among beans. Here is the error [image]

**Down below I'll share the code starting from Controller to Mappers**

**RoomController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/rooms")
public class RoomController {

    private final RoomService roomService;

    public RoomController(RoomService roomService) {
        this.roomService = roomService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<RoomDto>> getAllRooms() {
        List<RoomDto> rooms = roomService.findAll();

        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(rooms);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<RoomDto> createRoom(@Valid @RequestBody CreateRoomDto createRoomDto) {
        RoomDto roomDto = roomService.save(createRoomDto);

        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .body(roomDto);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteRoomById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        roomService.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**RoomService.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RoomServiceImpl implements RoomService {

    private final RoomRepository roomRepository;
    private final RoomMapper roomMapper;

    public RoomServiceImpl(RoomRepository roomRepository,
                                                 RoomMapper roomMapper) {
        this.roomRepository = roomRepository;
        this.roomMapper = roomMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public RoomDto save(CreateRoomDto createRoomDto) {
        Room room = roomMapper.toRoom(createRoomDto);
        return roomMapper.toRoomDto(roomRepository.save(room));
    }

    @Override
    public List<RoomDto> findAll() {
        return roomRepository.findAll().stream().map(roomMapper::toRoomDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public RoomDto findById(Long id) {
        Room room = roomRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Room with id " + id + " not found!"));
        return roomMapper.toRoomDto(room);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        roomRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**RoomMapper.java**

```
@Service
public class RoomMapperImpl implements RoomMapper {

    private final LectureMapper lectureMapper;

    public RoomMapperImpl(LectureMapper lectureMapper) {
        this.lectureMapper = lectureMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public RoomDto toRoomDto(Room room) {
        return RoomDto.builder()
                .id(room.getId())
                .name(room.getName())
                .description(room.getDescription())
                .number(room.getNumber())
                .lectures(room.getLectures().stream().map(
                        lectureMapper::toLectureDto
                ).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Room toRoom(CreateRoomDto createRoomDto) {
        return Room.builder()
                .name(createRoomDto.getName())
                .description(createRoomDto.getDescription())
                .number(createRoomDto.getNumber())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public RoomSmallDto toRoomSmallDto(Room room) {
        return RoomSmallDto.builder()
                .id(room.getId())
                .name(room.getName())
                .description(room.getDescription())
                .number(room.getNumber())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**LectureMapper.java**

```
@Service
public class LectureMapperImpl implements LectureMapper {

    private final CohortMapper cohortMapper;
    private final InstructorMapper instructorMapper;
    private final RoomMapper roomMapper;

    public LectureMapperImpl(CohortMapper cohortMapper,
                                                     InstructorMapper instructorMapper,
                                                     RoomMapper roomMapper) {
        this.cohortMapper = cohortMapper;
        this.instructorMapper = instructorMapper;
        this.roomMapper = roomMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public LectureDto toLectureDto(Lecture lecture) {
        return LectureDto.builder()
                .id(lecture.getId())
                .title(lecture.getTitle())
                .description(lecture.getDescription())
                .startDate(lecture.getStartDate())
                .endDate(lecture.getEndDate())
                .cohort(cohortMapper.toCohortSmallDto(lecture.getCohort()))
                .instructor(instructorMapper.toInstructorSmallDto(lecture.getInstructor()))
                .room(roomMapper.toRoomSmallDto(lecture.getRoom()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**CohortMapper.java**

```
@Service
public class CohortMapperImpl implements CohortMapper {

    private final LectureMapper lectureMapper;

    public CohortMapperImpl(LectureMapper lectureMapper) {
        this.lectureMapper = lectureMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public CohortDto toCohortDto(Cohort cohort) {
        return CohortDto.builder()
                .id(cohort.getId())
                .major(cohort.getMajor())
                .year(cohort.getYear())
                .lectures(cohort.getLectures().stream().map(
                        lectureMapper::toLectureDto
                ).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public CohortSmallDto toCohortSmallDto(Cohort cohort) {
        return CohortSmallDto.builder()
                .id(cohort.getId())
                .major(cohort.getMajor())
                .year(cohort.getYear())
                .build();
    }


}
```

**Entities**

```
@Data
@Builder
public class CohortSmallDto {
    private Long id;
    private String major;
    private int year;
}

---------------------------------------

@Data
@Builder
public class CohortDto {

    private Long id;
    private String major;
    private int year;

    private List<LectureDto> lectures;
}

---------------------------------------

@Data
@Builder
public class LectureDto {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    private CohortSmallDto cohort;
    private InstructorSmallDto instructor;
    private RoomSmallDto room;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you asking how to fix the cycles, or what are the cycles? `RoomMapper` uses `LectureMapper` and `LectureMapper` uses `RoomMapper` - clear cycle here, same situation with `CohortMapper`

Comment: I tried @Lazy but it didn't hep

Comment: Also, you see even if its cycle I am not directly using cohortDto, I am using cohortSmallDto which should not cause circle

Comment: Move `toCohortSmallDto` into a separate component.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding below

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

to your `application.properties` but its better to avoid such dirty tricks if possible.